# How do i google something by typing "Google "something"?"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bots

How do I google something by just typing Google "something"

```
else if (textBox1.Text == "Open google")
{
    textBox2.Clear();
    textBox2.Text += "Wait a second " + Name;
    s.SpeakAsync("Wait a second " + Name);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.no/");
}
```

Comment: What's that code?

Answer (score 2):

You open the site `https://www.google.no/search?q=...` and replace the `...` with a [url encoded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) copy of your search

For example looking for "this is a search" would be `https://www.google.no/search?q=this%20is%20a%20search`